# What kind of rhythm should I use for these settings?

Tags: rhythm

I am not particularly experienced with using rhythm in creative writing so please note that I am only a beginner. By "rhythm" I am referring to anything along the lines of syllable count, sentence structure, etc.

I have been given a task of writing a short story.

If any of you could advise me on the following scenes, I would be most grateful.

- A bleak, cold, November morning. Our main character is at a remembrance march.
- A classic war scene similar to the D-Day landings. Our character is one of attacking soldiers.

Also, could you suggest a suitable register to write in?

Comment: Are you writing a *story* or a *poem?*

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  Questions about what to write aren't on-topic here and your two specific requests seem close to that.  However, if you were to provide an excerpt (several paragraphs) from something where you want to improve the rhythm, we could help you with that.  Ideally you would also point to an example of something that you think has good rhythym, to better illustrate what you're aiming for.  I'm going to put this on hold pending those edits; we'll be happy to reopen after you [edit] the post.  Thanks.

Comment: @Monica: I don't really agree with you. This is a question "how to write", not "what to write". I must say this approaches the subject from a very weird angle ("my wife cheats on me. What kind of ammo will be best to kill her?") but I could answer it... providing the asker tells us what's his problem. I mean, 9mm will do the job just fine, why asking?

Comment: @SF. my concern is the two specific topics in the question (the bullet points) -- that's what sounds "what should I write?" to me.  I think there is an on-topic question in here, but the question needs some editing to clarify (as you kind of hint at in your comment too).  If you think you know what the question is, please offer an edit.  I'd rather we have open, answerable questions than closed ones, after all.

Comment: What is "a suitable register"? B♭4?

Comment: Nope. It's like I went to Seasoned Advice and asked "I want to make plain scrambled eggs and black instant coffee. What vessels should I use, what is the optimum temperature, how long do I prepare them, what spices should I add? What direction should I stir the scrambled eggs, and how many teaspoons of sugar should I add to the coffee?"